# Vuejs : Open a collapse menu when a particular tab is active and close it when it is not active

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have two methods forceOpenSettings() and forceCloseSettings(). I need these for opening and closing of a collapsable section. the methods are working fine as I tested it separately. But I need to do this based on a condition, I have b-tab with 4 tabs. Out of which when i click on a tab the collpase should open, and whenever the tab becomes inactive , the collapse must close

```
<b-tabs content-class="mt-3">
  <b-tab title="First" active><p>I'm the first tab</p></b-tab>
  <b-tab title="Second"><p>I'm the second tab</p></b-tab>
</b-tabs>
```

The same thing I'am achieving in a b-collapse using @show and @hide and it working fine,

```
<b-collapse role="tabpanel" @show="forceOpenSettings" @hide="forceCloseSettings">......</b-collapse>
```

Comment: when clicked , check that class attribule like having action class then call method accordingly

Comment: @DavidJawHpan So do I need to call a method on click of the tab to achieve this, and should the checking be done in that method ?

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JS: Here is a Dynamic iterator that will check if active is set as an attribute...

```js
function opendiv() {
  document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = "block";
}

function closediv() {
  document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = "none";
}

let tabs = document.getElementsByTagName('b-tab');
for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  tabs[i].addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (tabs[i].getAttribute("active") !== null) {
      opendiv();
    } else {
      closediv();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<b-tabs content-class="mt-3">
  <b-tab title="First">
    <p>I'm the first tab</p>
  </b-tab>
  <b-tab title="Second" active>
    <p>I'm the second tab</p>
  </b-tab>
</b-tabs>

<div id="myDiv" style="display:none;">Show this div when second tab has an attribute named 'active'</div>
```

Get the elements by their tag name... Then write your conditional statement to search for the second iteration of the elements using the key `1`, which is the second tab, check to see if the attribute is not null, which means it is set, but set to nothing. If it is not present in the tag, then it will return null.

```js
  let tabs = document.getElementsByTagName('b-tab');

  if(tabs[1].getAttribute("active") !== null){
    // run opendiv();
  }else{
    // run closediv();
  }
```

Comment: Your code is working. But will there be some hooks in vue to achieve this ? Iam using the same function at other place

Comment: Let me explain something. I'am doing the same thing for a b-collapse or accordion ( for vue it is b-collapse ). In that you have the (at)show and (at)hide and I add these to b-collapse tag and it works fine (at)show="forceOpenSettings" @hide="forceCloseSettings". when this accordion is shown forceOpenSettings -settings accordion closes , when this accordion closes forceCloseSettings - settings accordion closes. This is already working in case of accordions as we have show and hide. But I want the same thing working for tab ( there are 4 tabs ) , I want this feature to work for the single tab

Answer (score 1):

Vue is data driven, you dont need functions to do this:

```js
{
  ...,
  data(){
    return {
      ...,
      active: 'first',
      tabs: ["first", "second", "third"]
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<b-tabs content-class="mt-3">
  <b-tab
    v-for="tab in tabs"
    :key="tab"
    :title="tab" 
    :active="active==tab" 
    @click="active=tab" 
    :style="`display:${active==tab? 'block':'none}`'"
  >
    <p>I'm the {{tab}} tab</p>
  </b-tab>

</b-tabs>
```

Ok extending this for interaction with b-collapse component

```js
{
  props: ["tab", "active"],
  computed(){
    collapse: {
      get: function(){
        return this.active == this.tab
      },
      set: function(value){
        this.$emit('update:active', this.tab)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- wrap in component for prop management -> no collapse[tab] needed than -->
<template>
<b-collapse 
  role="tabpanel" 
  v-model="collapse"
 ><slot></slot></b-collapse>
 </template>

 <!-- then in scope of tabs -->
 <wrapped-collapse 
    v-for="tab in tabs"
    :key="tab"
    :active.sync="active" :tab="tab"  
  >...</wrapped-collapse>
```

Comment: I need to call the method forceOpenSettings and forceCloseSetting, I'am having a few conditions inside that. I'am doing that for b-collapse as you can see

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple functions to do this.

You can have one function that removes the `active` attribute from all the tabs and then just makes the one you clicked on `active`. Just give all the `<b-tab>` components a class of `tab` and then you can use this one function for all the tabs that has a class of `tab`. Then you can run the method with the `@click="doTabs()"` directive.

I've updated the answer to apply to a Vue instance.

Run the snippet to see it in action.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    doTabs() {
      const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab')
      tabs.forEach(i => i.removeAttribute('active'))
      event.currentTarget.setAttribute('active', true)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.tab {padding: 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; cursor: pointer; display: flex; display: block}
[active] {background-color: #eee}
.content {padding-left: 20px; font-size: 12px; visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; transition: all 0.2s ease; margin-top: -40px}
[active] .content {visibility: visible; opacity: 1;margin-top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div title="First" class="tab" @click="doTabs()" active>
    <p>I'm the first tab</p>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Here is all the<br>accordion content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div title="Second" class="tab" @click="doTabs()">
    <p>I'm the second tab</p>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Here is all the<br>accordion content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the code for adding and removing active from the tabs right ? My requirement is like you have section in you page , an accordion for example. the accordion must show or open when the tab is active and close when it not active @Ludolfyn

Comment: Hey @JithinB . For sure, that makes sense. The above function will work for that too. It's just the css that will make it open. Give me a minute then I'll update the answer to illustrate how you could do it with an accordion etc.

Comment: Let me explain something. I'am doing the same thing for a b-collapse or accordion ( for vue it is b-collapse ). In that you have the (at)show and (at)hide and I add these to b-collapse tag and it works fine (at)show="forceOpenSettings" @hide="forceCloseSettings". when this accordion is shown forceOpenSettings -settings accordion closes , when this accordion closes forceCloseSettings - settings accordion closes. This is already working in case of accordions as we have show and hide. But I want the same thing working for tab ( there are 4 tabs ) , I want this feature to work for the single tab

Comment: ( note (at)- is for at the rate symbol ) cant use more than 1 in comments

Comment: Yes, and the above does just that.